# How to get CNAME value when using wildcard domains in nginx?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I've setup nginx to listen to wildcard subdomains like:

```
server_name ~^pages.(?<domain>.+)$ ;
```

Now I want to pass the $domain variable to every request using a rewrite:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?domain=$domain
```

The problem I have is that $domain might be something like **pages.domain.com** which is in fact a DNS CNAME entry with the value **site123.example.net**.

How do I get the value **site123.example.net** in nginx to pass it to my scripts?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such information in HTTP request, DNS resolution is done on the client side and initially requested host name (as entered in browser address bar) and resolved ip address are all that is used.

Comment: You can write script for generate map of domains and include this map in config.